# Getting "uninitialized constant" in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and feeling my way, but this has me stumped.
I moved some constants to a separate module ie:

```
module Fns
 Fclick = "function() { alert(\"You clicked the map.\");}\n"
 ...
end
```

then in my controller added:

```
require "fns"
class GeomapController < ApplicationController
  def index
      fstring = Fns::Fclick
  ...
  end
```

but when I run the server I get:

```
uninitialized constant Fns::Fclick
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me if the module is in lib/fns.rb.

For the sake of convention use all-caps for constant names: http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7